# Error while installing FFMPEG under Raspbian (Debian 8 Jessie)

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi3, raspbian-wheezy

I am attempting to get FFMPEG installed on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian (based on Debian 8 Jessie)

When I run the install command I get:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 8:1.0.0) but it is not going to be         installed
          Depends: libavdevice54 (>= 8:1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter3 (>= 8:1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat54 (>= 8:1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpostproc52 (>= 8:1.0.0) but 6:0.git20120821-4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Has anyone seen this error before? The Debian site states: Be careful, FFmpeg is not available on Debian 8 Jessie.

Is there a way to get FFMPEG installed on Debian 8 Jessie?

UPDATE: I am going through this: https://www.assetbank.co.uk/support/documentation/install/ffmpeg-debian-squeeze/ffmpeg-debian-jessie/

Hopefully this works.

UPDATE:

This got ffmpeg built from source and installed but the script I am running that needs ffmpeg seems to think it should be in user/bin/ffmpeg while its actually installed in user/local/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: The easiest solution is to edit your script so it points to your compiled `ffmpeg`.